# How to get user's email on sign in with google in METEOR.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, google-signin

I am new to meteor . I wish to do a google+ sign in in meteor.js ,
I am using "accounts-ui" package and have put `{{> loginButtons}}` in the html file .
Everything works just fine , except that I wish to access the email id of the user and I can not figure out how to access the response from google+ .

Comment: can you login with google account?

Comment: yup , I am able to log in  , I am able to see my name after I login .

Comment: after login try `Meteor.user()` in browser console

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`accountsClientOrServer.onLogin(func)`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_onlogin) callback, for example:

```
Accounts.onLogin(function(user){
  console.log(user.user.services.google.email);
});
```